# SQL operator? What is this that I am looking at?

Tags: sql, nested-sets

I found an example of the nested set model that I am trying to use on a project. I can't understand just a small part of what is happening which in turn makes it so I can't tweak it to my needs. The example looks like this:

```sql
LOCK TABLE nested_category WRITE;

SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt)
VALUES ('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I don't understand what is going on in on the line `SELECT @myRight:=rgt FROM nested_category`.
More specifically, I am not grasping "@myRight := rgt". What is going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is assigning the value of `rgt` from the row in `nested_category` where `name = 'TELEVISIONS'` to the variable `@myRight`.

Comment: Is LOCK table necessary for that all to happen?

Comment: Yes it's needed as the table going through an update transaction.

Comment: Plus it keeps the data from changing between the SELECT and the UPDATEs.

Comment: You may want to have some error handling in there, though, to enure the table gets unlocked again.

Answer (score 1):

This is assignment operator in mysql. Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
```

Variable `myRight` will be filled with the value from column `rgt`in table `nested_category`

Answer (score 0):

User-Defined Variables are supported in at least [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) and [Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848809.aspx).